# Minitoc Package: Secttoc works just after changing section to part and back to section

Tags: sectioning, appendices, parts, minitoc

I have no idea why, but if I use `\secttoc` it works only for the section if I change the section to "part", compile it, and change it back to "section"

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}  
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eurosym}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[nohyperlinks,printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage[flushmargin, hang]{footmisc}


\begin{document}
\dosecttoc
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\adjuststc
section{Anhang}
\mtcsetrules{secttoc}{off}
\renewcommand{\stctitle}{Anhangsverzeichnis}
\secttoc
\subsection{Exampletext}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\section{Anhang}` is better than `section{Anhang}`, I suppose ;-) But your question is quite unclear to me

Comment: Tables of Contents usually require two latex runs for the change to propagate to the output: the first writes it to an auxiliary file; the second reads the auxiliary file and produces the updated information.  Are you sure you aren't keeping one step out of sync with the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to delete the `\adjuststc` command. You also need to fix the typo `\section{Anhang}` not `section{Anhang}` as @Christian Hupfer said.

In your MWE there is nothing that needs to be adjusted, so I guess `\adjuststc` is causing a problem, not fixing a problem that doesn't exist.

You need to run LaTeX more than once to get the right output. If your LaTeX editor doesn't do that automatically, an easy way is use a program like `latexmk` or `texify` (depending on what TeX distribution you are using).

Note, Minitoc can be a bit fragile if you make a "low level" mistake like this. If you still get a crash, delete all the temporary files like `*.maf`, `*.mtc*`, `*,stc*` and try again.